# translate sql data into c# objects

Tags: c#

I'm retrieving a group of customers and orders from sql, what's the best way to translate this into a list Customer objects and their orders?

```
public class Customer
{
   public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking? It's not clear what you have, what you want, and what the problem is.

Comment: Is the question what is the best way to create POCO objects that represent your data?  I think it depend on the method with which you are retrieving them from persistent storage. SQL? Web Services?  Have you explored EF?

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive - that's it on the nose, i just updated my post to say i'm getting the records from sql. I have the objects i just want to know the best way to fill them with data from the database.

Comment: In the past, I have created class to encapsulate that abstraction, but these days ORM is the way to go.  I will post a link to EF.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive - can't use ORM for this case. You have very simple example of former to illustrate a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are presently retrieving data out of SQL, you should consider Entity Framework (EF 4.1).  this allows you to "Code first" and then hydrate those objects with results from your SQL database.

For more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Despite your question isn't clear much, by looking at your class `Customer`, it is known that the class contains the `List` of object `Order`, so the relation is one to many. So, if you have a `web application`, its better to get as much as record possible in `one query`, so that there are not `multiple queries` firing. In `desktop application`, `multiple queries` firing doesn't hurt that much. If you have huge data, you can do server side or database level `paging`. In desktop application, one approach could be, to use `DataReader` as it is performant, so when customer is loaded, you load the list of order as well, this will happen for each customer object you are creating.